# xxd output only the binary

Tags: linux, binary, xxd

Using the command :

`xxd -b some_text`

will output the binary representation and the original text:

```
000054c: 11101111 10100001 10110110 00010000 01011011 10000110  ....[.
0000552: 01111000 11001000 01010101 11000101 11101111 10101111  x.U...
0000558: 10010111 11101010 00011001 01010100 10101010 10001110  ...T..
```

How can I have the utility output only the binary without anything else?

Comment: Do you want something like `xxd -p file.txt` ?

Answer (score 0):

That combination is not listed in its [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xxd).  However, you could filter the result using awk/sed/perl (your choice).  For the given example, sed suffices:

```
xxd -b some_text | sed -e 's/^[^:]*:[[:space:]][[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]][[:space:]]*.\{6,6\}$//'
```

That is:

- In the first "-e" option, remove everything through the first ":", followed by whitespace.
- In the second "-e" option, starting with at least one space
- followed by 6 characters (it's unclear if those can be spaces, but testing seems to confirm they are not)
- strip off the entire matched string

You could replace the "[[:space:]][[:space:]]*" with exactly the number of spaces which you want to match, but though more verbose, the character class is also more powerful.

Alternatively (since whitespace is a default field separator in awk), one could pipe through awk:

```
xxd -b some_text | awk '{ printf "%s %s %s %s %s %s\n", $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7 }'
```

though as a rule I use the simplest tool which works.

Comment: Thanks, but what about the beginning of each line, how to overwrite those? For example how to get rid of 000054c.

Comment: @TryingHard I guess I am asking how to skip the first 8 characters of each line

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the binary, and not even the offset, you could extend Thomas Dickey's `sed` one-liner to strip the offset too:

```
xxd -b some_text | sed -e 's/^.*: //; s/[[:space:]][[:space:]]*.\{6,6\}$//'
```

Answer (score 0):

"xxd" do not take "some_text" as input but "infile".
Shorter answer using 'cut' command printing 6 fields (2 to 7) :

```
xxd -b some_file | cut -d\  -f2-7
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
xxd -b some_file > /tmp/output
cut -d: -f2 |egrep "[01 ]+"
```